# Failed to classify image - check the inner exception for more details

Tags: c#, android, tensorflow, xamarin, custom-renderer

I'm using Jim Bennett's "OnDeviceImageClassification" plugin, to try to classify an image taken by a Camera Custom Renderer I did. The problem is, that when it gets to classifying the image taken from the stream:`var tags = await CrossImageClassifier.Current.ClassifyImage(fileStream);`, It crashes.

Visual Studio 19, throws "Failed to classify image - check the inner exception for more details"

Here's the complete error:

> Xam.Plugins.OnDeviceCustomVision.ImageClassifierException   Mensaje =
> Failed to classify image - check the inner exception for more details
> Origen = mscorlib   Seguimiento de la pila:   at
> Xam.Plugins.OnDeviceCustomVision.ImageClassifierImplementation.ClassifyImage
> (System.IO.Stream imageStream) [0x00184] in
> <377ca536dcf942e7853c2239a662e7b2>:0    at
> CustomRenderer.Droid.CameraPageRenderer.TakePhotoButtonTapped
> (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x001cf] in
> C:\tensorflow1\CC +
> IA\XamarinCameraRender-master\CustomRenderer\CustomRenderer.Android\CameraPageRenderer.cs:263
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0
> (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021
> at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 ()
> [0x00000] in <55654ebe9f2a48e6bade2862bb243f94>:0    at
> Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
> <55654ebe9f2a48e6bade2862bb243f94>:0    at
> Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
> native__this) [0x00008] in <55654ebe9f2a48e6bade2862bb243f94>:0    at
> (wrapper dynamic-method)
> Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.1(intptr,intptr)

This is the complete method where the image is created, streamed and classified:

```
        async void TakePhotoButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        camera.StopPreview();

        var context = this.Context;

        var image = textureView.Bitmap;

        try
        {
            
            var absolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
            var folderPath = absolutePath; 
               filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format("photo_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"               ", ex.Message);
        }


            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);              
            await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 25, fileStream);


            var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            intent.SetData(uri);
            MainActivity.Instance.SendBroadcast(intent);


         var tags = await CrossImageClassifier.Current.ClassifyImage(fileStream);
         var result = tags.OrderByDescending(t => t.Probability).First().Tag;

        resultText.Text = result;
```

This is the output log:

> 06-26 19:04:45.641 D/skia    (24234): --- Failed to create image
> decoder with message 'unimplemented' 06-26 19:04:45.671
> D/DRM/DcfDecoder(24234): decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream 06-26
> 19:04:45.672 D/DRM/DcfDecoder(24234): decodeDrmImageIfNeeded:
> [0][0][0][0][0] 06-26 19:04:45.672 D/DRM/DcfDecoder(24234):
> decodeDrmImageIfNeeded: headerSize = 0 06-26 19:04:45.673
> D/DRM/DcfDecoder(24234): isDrmFile: version is not dcf version 1, no
> oma drm file
> **Xam.Plugins.OnDeviceCustomVision.ImageClassifierException:** 'Failed to classify image - check the inner exception for more details'

Comment: did you check the inner exception for more detail?

Comment: @Jason, it only gives me the option to copy details, which I have attached. I have pasted the output logs in the edit.

Comment: that does not to be the innerexception, that looks like a copy of the output log